# awk or sed help for munging first line of a CSV or TSV file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I was messing around with awk because I think it's far simpler to munge the header of a tab delimited or csv file with this tool..

I have two types of files (either comma, or tab delimited) and all I would like to do is to modify the header (NR =1) to:

1. lowers the case of all the words
2. replace any spaces with underscores for each
   field name.. Ex. changing *Cancer Type* bellow to *cancer_type*

> Cancer Type, Assembly Version, Chromosome, Chromosome
>   start, Chromosome end

All I've managed to do so far is to list the first line

> awk 'NR == 1' test2.csv

Well I'm at a loss. In any case I'll probably run this script (sed or awk) prior to doing some downstream modifications.

Any help (or pointing me to a good tutorial/one liners) would be much appreciated.

EDIT

Hi I should edit to clarify this. 
I will be taking starting with a file, and ending with the same file but with the header changed.

I could get two versions of the file.

***The CSV***

> Cancer Type, Assembly Version, Chromosome, Chromosome start,
>   Chromosome end

**After:**

> cancer_type, assembly_version, chromosome, chromosome_start,
>   chromosome_end

***The TSV***

> Cancer Type\t Assembly Version\t Chromosome\t Chromosome start\t
>   Chromosome end

**After:**

> cancer_type\t assembly_version\t chromosome\t chromosome_start\t
>   chromosome_end

Having said that I think approaches are almost working..

**EDIT 2**
The os is OS X 10.7.+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -r '1 {s/.*/\L&/;s/\b\s\b/_/g}' infile>outfile
```

---

```
$ echo Cancer Type, Assembly Version, Chromosome, Chromosome start, Chromosome end|sed -r '1 {s/.*/\L&/;s/\b\s\b/_/g}'
cancer_type, assembly_version, chromosome, chromosome_start, chromosome_end
```

Comment: IMHO the `\s` is not ok. The input string can be delimited by `,` or by tab. I think `\s` will replace tab as well.

Comment: @TrueY Hmm, at the moment, there are two non word characters between the words. Usually changing commas to tabs is a nonconsuming process. If this occurs (consuming of a character) the Regex must be changed. Regex works only for a given issue.

Comment: Then change it to a literal space.

Comment: Changing the Regex at this point would make sense only if there were reliable statements to the upcoming tab delimited format. I assume, changing from CSV to tab delimited does't delete some characters.

Comment: I think almost there. Though it should work on the infile. One of the reasons I want to do infile is because these files can get larger then 10gb..

Comment: @prussiap infile/outfile added.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify only the header and print the remaining lines as is then try something like this with `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{$0=tolower($0);gsub(/\y \y/,"_",$0)}1' csv
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well OP wants to replace the header of the original file, not just print out the result to the console.

At first I tried to solve it with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), as I know it better. But [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) has not inplace editing feature, so some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) workaround is needed:

```
# Unsafe hack
#{ rm infile; awk 'NR==1{...}1' >infile;} <infile
#Ed Morton's correction
awk 'NR==1{...}1' infile >tmp && mv tmp infile
```

This works, but it uses 1 extra `fork` for the `rm` command.  It would be better to use inplace editing. [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) supports this feature. To use perl is a little bit overkill, so I corrected a little bit [captha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468910/captcha)'s [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution:

```
sed -i '1{s/\b \b/_/g;s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g;}' infile
```

The infile before:

```
Cancer Type, Assembly Version, Chromosome, Chromosome start, Chromosome end
One 1,Two 2
```

The infile after:

```
cancer_type, assembly_version, chromosome, chromosome_start, chromosome_end
One 1,Two 2
```

Comment: gawk has an inplace editing feature, please look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/QM51VPAlw4I) pt.#6

Comment: `cmd > infile < infile` is never a good idea.  The initial `rm` is totally unnecessary, since `cmd > foo` will truncate foo at startup.  The "in-place" editing feature of `sed` and `perl` are identical to doing shell redirects, so gain nothing in terms of actual run-time behavior.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: your first sencence is right. The rest is not! This will run in a separate subshell. `Rm` removes the file, but i-node is not removed, as it is opened (for input). Now you can create a new i-node with a new name (which happen to be the same as the deleted name). When subshell is over, the original i-node is removed by the kernel. It works nicely! Try it!

Comment: Whether it works or not (and trying it on one or 2 systems IMHO would NOT be proof that it works in general!), that code is a heck of a lot less clear than `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: This is probably because I don't know sed quite well but running the above command returns : `sed -i '1{s/\b \b/_/g;s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g;}' test2.csv` **returns** 
sed: 1: "test2.csv": undefined label 'est2.csv'

Comment: @EdMorton: You are completely right! And Your version not only cleaner, but much safer! Code corrected!

Comment: @prussiap: I tested with `GNU sed version 4.2.1` on a Debian PC and it works ok. Maybe Your `sed` is not a GNU `sed`.

Comment: @TrueY That is an interesting technique which works nicely in most (possibly all) shells *if* you have write permission on the directory. If the user does not have write permission on the directory but does on the file, data will be lost.  This is not a safe technique!

Comment: Hi TrueY.. well i'm osx which apparently does the `-i` differently.. running the original command gives me this: `sed: 1: "test2.csv": undefined label 'est2.csv'`. Trying to do it with the `-e` parameter `sed -i -e '1{s/\b \b/_/g;s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g;}' test2.csv` gives me:`LCancer LType   LAssembly LVersion      LChromosome     LChromosome start       LChromosome end`

Comment: @prussiap: Unfortunately different op.sys.-es use different arguments. The target OS was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand your question, but as far as I understood this should solve it:

```
head -1 test2.csv | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/ /_/g' > tmp.txt
tail -n +2 test2.csv >> tmp.txt
```

- `head` picks the first line
- the first `sed` option makes everything lower-case
- the second `sed` option converts all spaces to underscores
- `tail` prints everything starting at line 2

`tmp.txt` now contains the complete result.

Comment: hi.. that seems to work but it doesn't replace the header line in the csv file ? Also what modifications would you need for a tab delimited file instead of a csv ?

Comment: @prussiap See my update of the answer. `sed` doesn't care about separators, it just parses and replaces, i.e. you could pick any separator you want.

Comment: IMHO it is a little bit overcomplicated. `sed` supports inplace editing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys both commands worked but for OS X you have to

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

then run your sed command

```
gsed -i '1{s/\b \b/_/g;s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g;}' infile
```

magic.. thanks guys.